# Method 'set(double)' is never used for my double variables but it is used for my string variable - in this arraylist class

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I am trying to put together an arraylist and I made a separate class to establish the objects used. I am able to get my getMethod and setMethod for my string variable to work but I am unable to figure out my setMethod for my double variables to work. I am able to get my getMethod for my double variables. The variable names all appear to be correct so I am stuck as to what is missing. Any help will be appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
public class MessierData {
private String messierLocation;
private double messierRA;
private double messierDEC;
private double messierAZ;
private double messierALT;


public MessierData(String messierLocation,double messierRA, double messierDEC,
                   double messierAZ, double messierALT ) {
    this.messierLocation = messierLocation;
    this.messierRA = messierRA;
    this.messierDEC = messierDEC;
    this.messierAZ = messierAZ;
    this.messierALT = messierALT;


}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return messierLocation;
}

public String getMessierLocation (){
    return messierLocation;
}

public void setMessierLocation(String messierLocation){
    this.messierLocation = messierLocation;
}

public double getMessierRA(){
    return messierRA;
}

public void setMessierRA( double messierRA){
    this.messierRA = messierRA;
}


public double getMessierDEC(){return messierDEC;}

public void setMessierDEC(double messierDEC){
    this.messierDEC = messierDEC;
}


public double getMessierAZ(){return messierAZ;}

public void setMessierAZ(double messierAZ){
    this.messierAZ = messierAZ;
}


public double getMessierALT(){return messierALT;}

public void setMessierALT( double messierALT){
    this.messierALT = messierALT;
}



  }
```

Just a reminder. The setMethod for my string is working properly. The setMethod for my double variables however are not.

Here is my arraylist:

```
private List<MessierData> messierList() {
    List<MessierData> messiervalues = new ArrayList<>();

    messiervalues.add(new MessierData(Andromeda.getAndromedaHorizon(),Andromeda.getAndromedaRA()
            ,Andromeda.getAndromedaDec(), Andromeda.getAndromedaAZ(),Andromeda.getAndromedaALT()));
    messiervalues.add(new MessierData(BeehiveCluster.getBeehiveHorizon(),BeehiveCluster.getBeehiveRA(),
            BeehiveCluster.getBeehiveDec(),BeehiveCluster.getBeehiveAZ(),BeehiveCluster.getBeehiveALT()));
    messiervalues.add(new MessierData(BlackEyeGalaxy.getBlackEyeHorizon(),BlackEyeGalaxy.getBlackEyeRA(),
            BlackEyeGalaxy.getBlackEyeDec(),BlackEyeGalaxy.getBlackEyeAZ(),BlackEyeGalaxy.getBlackEyeALT()));
    messiervalues.add(new MessierData(BodesGalaxy.getBodesHorizon(),BodesGalaxy.getBodesRA()
            ,BodesGalaxy.getBodesDec(),BodesGalaxy.getBodesAZ(),BodesGalaxy.getBodesALT()));
    messiervalues.add(new MessierData(ButterflyCluster.getButterflyHorizon(),ButterflyCluster.getButterflyRA(),
            ButterflyCluster.getButterflyDec(),ButterflyCluster.getButterflyAZ(),ButterflyCluster.getButterflyALT()));
    messiervalues.add(new MessierData(CetusGalaxy.getCetusHorizon(),CetusGalaxy.getCetusRA(),
            CetusGalaxy.getCetusDec(),CetusGalaxy.getCetusAZ(),CetusGalaxy.getCetusALT()));

 return messiervalues;

}
```

Comment: *the setMethod for my double variables however are not*.. how do you infer so? Do you have a test code where you're consuming these methods?

Comment: In android studio the setMethod for my double objects aren’t highlighted. When my code is compiled my logcat shows my string values in my arraylist but not my double values. I can provide that code if necessary.